# Email user not required

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like set email to not required on my User entities. How do what ?
I've searched in FOSUserBundle/config/ but i don't find any "required" parameter about email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following Tib's answer, here is the way I did it. It's working fine :

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true)),
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email_canonical", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true))
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser {
    // ...
}
```

## EDIT :

The previous solution is easy to implement and was working fine, but after updating Symfony to version 2.1.8 and without changing anything in my app, generating entities failes throwing a Doctrine mapping exception (Invalid field override ...)

In spite of loosing a lot of time trying to solve that issue, I was just stucked.

Then I finally realized that FOSUserBundle provides lot of features I don't use, but doesn't really fit my needs, which are quite basic.

I need to disable email requirement because my app user management is "software like" : no registration, no email sending, no profil, user and roles managed only by admin, etc...

I was adapting a tool not designed for my needs. So I decided to make my own implementation of Symfony security.

It is a little more work, but it's not very difficult and the result is far better and more flexible than adapting FOSUserBundle. Of course, for a "classic" website or web app, FOSUserBundle is the best.

If you are in this case too, I suggest you to do so. Here is the doc to begin : [Security in the Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) and [Security in the CookBook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/index.html)

I hope this can help you.

*Sorry for my poor english, I hope it is intelligible*

Comment: With Symfony 2.4.4 this solution still works! Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

Check this PR https://github.com/doctrine/orm-documentation/pull/117/files and look at @AttributeOverrides

Comment: Yes, AttributeOverrides look very nice ! ;)

Answer (score -4):

You need to override following methods in the entity User.

```
class User extends BaseUser // inheritance from fos
{
   /**
   * @var string
   * @ORM\column(type="string", name="email", length=255, unique=true, )
   * @Assert\Email(
   *     checkMX = true
   * )*/
   protected $email
}
}
```

You need to change Table definition to:

```
class User extends BaseUser // inheritance from fosUserBundle
    {
       /**
       * @var string
       * @ORM\column(type="string", name="email", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true )
       */
       protected $email
    }
}
```

Same thing is needed for emailCanonical attribute.

If that not pass. You will need to copy entire model from FOS into your bundle and then change it as I wrote.

check the doc: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.0/Resources/doc/doctrine.md

Regards Max

Comment: I can't replace 'email' attribute (MappingException: Duplicate definition of column 'email' on entity '[...]\Entity\User' in a field or discriminator column mapping.). How replace th mapping ? i'm lost, i use annotation for my entities, but in FOSUserBundle i found a lot of .xml configurations files :/

Comment: I was making sth like this and it was required to copy entire entity from FOSUserBundle and fix namespaces. Then change your email annotations to be not required.